# Is there a nice way to convert a null-delimited bytea column to a text[] in postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, bytea

I'm currently writing some code which reads [the `pg_trigger` catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-trigger.html): specifically the `tgargs` column:

> `tgargs` `bytea`
> Argument strings to pass to trigger, each NULL-terminated

There's two problems I think I need to solve:

- Is there a postgres function to split the `bytea` value on `NULL`s and get a postgres array back? I've had a look at [this documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html) but couldn't find anything promising.
- Converting bytes into `text`: which encoding is correct? Does it depend on the configured server encoding?